# Telegram bot getUpdates field empty even though I disabled privacy in Botfather

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot

Going to my bot's `getMe` URL I get:

`{"ok":true,"result":{"id":1966270303,"is_bot":true,"first_name":"{botname}","username":"{botname}_bot","can_join_groups":true,"can_read_all_group_messages":true,"supports_inline_queries":false}}`

Which I assume means that it should be able to read group messages. Yet when I add it to a group (and send a dozen messages) and give it admit rights it still returns `{ "ok": true, "result": [] }`
in `/getUpdates`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the "privacy mode" as explained in this [FAQ Entry](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get). Note that

- making a bot admin in a group effectively turns off group privacy for that group
- if you change the privacy setting with `@Botfather`, then you need to remove & re-add your groups to the group. Otherwise the changed setting doesn't take effect.